# PCLStorage/ZipArchive Difference between debug and release

Tags: zip, xamarin.forms

Hello all you clever folks in this great city called stackoverflow.
I come to you with a problem i can't seem to figure out.

My issue is that i am developing an app using xamarin forms in vs2015.
In this app i download some zipped data (image/audio) from a webservice and saves it to my phone with the nuget PCLStorage and (when needed) unzips a file to display/play.

The app works fine when using "Debug" mode but when i package the app as apk and install it on my phone, i throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when i try to open the zip file with ziparchive
The CheckExistsaAsync tells me the file exists, and the await DisplayAlert tells me the length of the stream is the same as when the file is saved. It is also the same length as the file when running in debug mode.

Here is the code that fails on me:

```
 IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
  if(await rootFolder.CheckExistsAsync("SavedData.zip") == ExistenceCheckResult.FileExists)
  {
    IFile file = await rootFolder.GetFileAsync("SavedData.zip");
    using(Stream s = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccess.Read))
    {
      await DisplayAlert("blabla", s.Length.ToString(), "ok");
      using(ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(s, ZipArchiveMode.Read, false))
      {
        //Code
      }
    }
  }
```

The line that failes on me is the using(ZipArchive zip = .....) line throwing the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALAS! i have found a solution!

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/45701/system-io-compression-zipfile-extracttodirectory-fails-in-release-mode

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to say but I am going to speculate File Permission Issue. Where does it download the file and does the Android App have the appropriate permissions to access that file location.

Comment: I have no permissions set for this as it's using FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage wich doesn't seem to need any (none that i've found in the documents for xamarin anyway). I do have read and write external storage permissions in the android manifest as those are used for other parts of the app

Comment: Do you have any more information around the exception? Can you post a stack trace in your question? There might be another hint there.